# EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I'm using an `EditText` inside a `TextInputLayout`, but after upgrading the support library to 23.2.0, I get this warning in the logcat, What's the difference between a regular `EditText` and a `TextInputEditText`? I can't seem to find any documentation for it.

Comment: i have upgraded my support library to 23.2.1 but still **TextInputEditText cannot be resolved in my code** . how did you Resolve it?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I was wondering this too, [Daniel Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35803291/253468) gathered the documentation, but to the untrained eye it doesn't mean much. Here's what it's all about: ["extract mode"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#FullscreenMode) is referring to the type of view that's shown when the space is too small, for example landscape on a phone. I'm using Galaxy S4 with Google Keyboard as input method editor (IME).

## Landscape UI without visible IME

Based on the focus (on Description) you can see `TextInputLayout` in action pushing the hint outside the editor. Nothing special here, this is what `TextInputLayout` is supposed to do.

[image: Landscape UI without visible IME]

## Landscape UI editing empty Name field

Editing the Name you can see that the IME doesn't give you a hint of what you're editing.

[image: Landscape UI editing empty Name field]

## Landscape UI editing empty Description field

Editing the Description you can see that the IME gives you a hint of what you're editing.

[image: Landscape UI editing empty Description field]

## Layout XMLs

The difference between the two fields is their type `EditText` VS `TextInputEditText`. The important thing here is that `TextInputLayout` has the `android:hint` and not the wrapped EditText, this is the case when `TextInputEditText`'s few lines of Java code makes a big difference.

### Name field

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Item Name"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

### Description field

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Item Description"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="4"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: i have upgraded my support library to 23.2.1 but still **TextInputEditText cannot be resolved in my code .** how did you Resolve it?

Comment: Do you have the design library as well? This is not in support.

Comment: Quick note: according to the docs, the `android:hint` property is supposed to go in `TextInputEditText` instead of `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: @DriesOeyen It works both ways, I think it's more clear on the outer layout, because on the UI it's the `TextInputLayout` that renders the hint and not the `*EditText`. If you check the code of `TextInputLayout.setEditText` you can see that it actually "steals" the hint and then clears it. That's why we need to use `TextInputEditText` which "steals" it back to be displayed in IME. *Interesting design...*

Comment: Same problem as @gikarasojokinene

Comment: @luxsypher Same response... that class is in package `android.support.design.widget` as you can see in XML, to use it you need [Design Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design), it's not in [v7 appcompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7). If this is not the issue I suggest creating a new question on SO.

Comment: @TWiStErRob  am using `com.android.support:design:23.2.1` but still TextInputEditText could not be resolved. i ended up dropping it and using the other way which is **putting EditText in a TextInputLayout**

Comment: @luxsypher  i ended up dropping it and using the other way which is **putting EditText in a TextInputLayout**

Comment: @luxsypher checkout my answer below

Comment: @gikarasojokinene I ended up doing the same, going back to a EditText and I ignore the warning

Comment: If I `type caste` the `TextInputEditText` to `EditText ` which are the cases where it can create problem ? TIA

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat it's an upcast, so it's safe. You should always use the most general type that provides you the functionality (=API) needed. Using `TextInputEditText` is an implementation detail of the UI.

Answer (score 35):

There is no documentation for it, but the class is a regular `EditText` with a single extra feature:

> Using this class allows us to display a hint in the IME when in 'extract' mode.

Specifically it sets the [`EditorInfo.hintText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html). You'll notice in the [`TextInputLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) class you can specify the hint and it's appearance rather than as part of the child `EditText` widget.

If you need to do that, you should use a `TextInputEditText` so it pays attention to the hint info you specified in the `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: any example? I have no idea what you're suggesting

Answer (score 4):

They are essentially the same thing, but I think the `TextInputEditText` has more features and possibly attributes. I changed to the `TextInputEditText` and everything worked and looked as it did before with the standard `EditText`.

Comment: I already use TextInputLayout, I'm asking about an alternative to the EditText called TextInputEditText

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the TextInputEditText but said layout. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that when your device is in landscape mode, `TextInputEditText` will show the hint, `EditText` won't.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and just deleted this line in my xml file:

```
android: fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```

and the error disappeared.