# Difference between TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, android-design-library

Need to know what actually difference between TextInputEditText and TextInputLayout, When should we use one of them.

Answer (score 36):

They are different layouts that complement each other functionalities.

- TextInputLayout extends LinearLayout
- TextInputEditText extends EditText

They were meant to be used together like following:

```
<TextInputLayout>
   <TextInputEditText/>
</TextInputLayout>
```

It's all there on the official docs:

**TextInputLayout:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

> Layout which wraps an EditText (or descendant) to show a floating label when the hint is hidden due to the user inputting text

**TextInputEditText:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html

> A special sub-class of EditText designed for use as a child of TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 2):

**TextInputLayout vs TextInputEditText**

`TextInputLayout` must contain a `TextInputEditText` instead of the normal `EditText` because it designed specially for using inside.

If you add `EditText` instead of `TextInputEditText` into `TextInputLayout` you will get the warning:

```
EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
```

For example if you wrap `EditText`, in Landscape Mode, you will get a big box, but the hint is missing.

`TextInputLayout` has features as floating hints, error labels, character counter, password visibility, animations and their customization

Comment: I didn't see this warning.

Answer (score 1):

Both `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`are different. As mentioned in the documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) the `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` are meant to be used like the below example(From official doc)

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Also the  main difference is when you compare `TextInputEditText` with `EditText`. The `TextInputEditText` provides a hint when when the layout is viewed in landscape mode. This is explained clearly in depth by [TWiStErRob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36269036/5106406). I hope this answers the question. Thank you.