# Which is more convenient to use? TextInputLayout & TextInputeEditText or EditText?

Tags: android

I am seeing these `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`, but since I am developing I noticed that the capabilities of these two methods can be used by `EditText` only.

I researched about `EditText`, and it only says that the advantage of `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` is that you can put a hint on it. `EditText` alone can also now use hint.

So I am wondering if I can just use `EditText` rather than use the two methods. Also, `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` is not anymore showing in the IntelliSense.

I am currently using Android Studio 3.0

Comment: It all depends upon your requirements

Comment: I was wondering why it was remove in the IntelliSense, maybe the developer want us not to use these `TextInputLayout` anymore or nah? 


That is why I am asking what is more convenient. Hmmm.


What can be your suggestion?

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833738/difference-between-textinputlayout-and-textinputedittext

Answer (score 0):

TextInputEditText is child of EditText whereas TextInputLayout is a linear layout which wraps an EditText (or descendant) to show a floating label when the hint is hidden due to the user inputting text. So if you need to show such thing then you use TextInputLayout otherwise edittext is good to go with. For further information please visit :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html